# Server Slowness

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stored-procedures

We created an ASP.NET MVC web application using C#, and we're using SQL Server database and hosted on AWS server.

The issue is when we increase the load on the web application, then the whole application goes down. And when check monitor graph on AWS then find out that CPU utilization is very high like 70 to 80%. Normally its like 20 to 25%. Also there is strange issue that according to UTC date at 5AM its again started  working properly.

I tried to optimize my stored procedures  and increase AWS server load capacity. Checked monitor activity in SQL Server. But did not found why everyday getting down at load time. What might be the reason behind them?

Here are some related please review once

- [CPU Utilization Graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/empZL.png)
- [Database Activity Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDp2J.png)

Please let me know how to find out the cause of these issues.

Comment: There is no way anyway can diagnose your issues with that limited information. You're going to need to dig in and investigate what is happening.

Comment: Agree, but according to experince, on Which way I can find out solution & What is reasion behind them?  @DaleK

Comment: I have no idea, you need an expert who can actually investigate your system.

Answer (score 1):

Providing basic insights here : The three most common causes of server slowdown: CPU, RAM, and disk I/O. CPU use can slow down the host as a whole and make it hard to complete tasks on time. Top and sar are two tools you can check the CPU.
As you are using stored proedure , if it might take more time in querying then this will results in IO Waits which utilmately results down in server slowdown. This is a basic troubleshooting [doc](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/troubleshooting-slow-servers) .